# How come to insert row with sqlite.JDBC with ubuntu it takes longer time than OSX?

Tags: java, macos, sqlite, ubuntu, jdbc

I wrote simple java program that read data from file ".xls" and store those into local database sqlite.
I've been having some problems about the time it takes to store those data by Ubuntu 12.04 and Mac OSX.
I've verified these operations (inserting rows) takes much longer with Ubuntu (around 15 minutes) than Mac OSX (around 32 seconds).
May someone help me to figure out the problem ? 
Here below I've attached my code.
PS: I'm sorry for my english.

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws IOException, BiffException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, WriteException {

    Main obj = new Main();

    if(!Database.access().exists()) {
        Database.access().connect("Proteomic.db");
        System.out.println("Uploading data from workSheets to database...");            
        obj.storeSheets("/Users/.../Desktop/File nurr1 vs ctrl-1"+".xls");
    }
    ...
```

method storeSheets

```
    public void storeSheets(String path) throws IOException, BiffException, SQLException
    {
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(path));
    String intestazione = new String();

    number_sheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();

    for(int k=0;k<number_sheets;k++)
    {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(k);
        String s_name = sheet.getName();

        int numeroRighe = sheet.getRows();
        int numeroColonne = sheet.getColumns();           

        ...
        ...

        Database.access().createTable(s_name); 

        for(int i=1;i<numeroRighe;i++) {
            cond=false; //condizione necessaria per non inserire righe parzialmente vuote
            for(int j = 0; j <= numeroColonne; j++)  {
                ...
                ...
            }
            //query per l'inserimento
            if(cond==true) {
                val.add("NULL");
                Database.access().insertRow(s_name,val); //insert operation
                val.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class Database.java

```
public class Database {

...
...
//other attributes and methods

public void insertRow(String name,ArrayList<String> vv) throws SQLException {

    Statement stat=(Statement) con.createStatement();
    String str1="INSERT INTO "+name+" "+"VALUES(";

    for(int i=0;i<vv.size();i++) {
        if(i==vv.size()-1)
            str1+=vv.get(i);
        else
            str1+=vv.get(i)+",";
    }
    str1+=")";

    stat.executeUpdate(str1);
}
```

Thank you all to help me.

Comment: Have you run a profiler on them? What's taking the time? Does `top` say that your Java program or Postgres is busy?

Comment: No i haven't a "run profiler" anyway the program jus retrieves data from workbook excel then store it into a table of my SQLITE database as i showed above.<br> My program to store all same data entry takes long around 32 second on OSX than 15 minutes on ubuntu 12.04. I really don't know why these operations taking different times on OSX and UBUNTU.

Comment: I resolved! The problem was that for each insert SQLIte DB executes a transaction and it takes too time if you want insert a lot of data, so disabling that thing I resolved :)